# Exception processing async thread queue Exception processing async thread queue java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, android

```
String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
    String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
    String[] contentsArray=contents.split("\\.");
    for(int i=0;i<=contentsArray.length;i++){
        String str=contentsArray[i];
        Log.e("FFFFFFF", str);
    }
```

While debugging, whenever the mouse pointer comes across the contentsArray an error pop up comes with heading

> 'JDI thread Evaluations' has encountered a problem. Exception processing async thread queue
>
> Exception processing async thread queue
>   Exception processing async thread queue
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

What may be the reason..plz help

Comment: @Tarsem i did that, and got the contents very well

Answer (score 0):

One Exception that you could face  `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` due to `<=` it must be `<` only

**check here** `for(int i=0;i<=contentsArray.length;i++)`

**It Must be** `for(int i=0;i<contentsArray.length;i++)`

Comment: @NitheshMohanan i know its not working now but this exception will occur after you solve current one !